# Working with a signup form, constantly saying password is incorrect

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I am creating a log-in form and this piece of code is giving me some trouble. I'm aware it may not be the most efficient or safe way but for now I simply need it to function, so I can test other aspects properly.
I have used a `count` in my `SELECT` statement but am now unsure how to turn that into an `IF ELSE` statement. If someone could please help me out that would be fantastic.

```
$result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count * FROM User WHERE LoginID = '$LoginID' AND password ='$password'");
if($result==1)
{ 
    echo "Log In Success!";
    echo $_SESSION['LoginID']; 
}
else
{
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";}
    echo '<a href="logIn2.html"> Click here to try again </a>'
}
```

I have also tried using

```
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($numrows != 0) { ... }
```

But I couldn't get that working either.
SQL injection or similar is not an issue as it will not have any actual security issues.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you say SQL injection is not an issue? Looks like a huge issue to me. Also, you're saving your users passwords in cleartext in the database?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying MySql and PHP.
As an idea about using `count` function to find a valid user, you should remember these notes:

> Note 1 : Using `count` function is like `Count(*)`.
>   Note 2 : If no records found `Count(*)` will return `null` instead of `0`, so you need another function like `ifnull(,)`.

So your select statement should be something like this:

```
SELECT IFNULL((SELECT count(*) FROM User WHERE LoginID = '$LoginID' AND password ='$password'), 0)
```

Actually I don't try that query in MySql so I hope someone edit it ;).

As your another idea your `select` statement will be this (using mysql_num_rows):

```
SELECT LoginID FROM User WHERE LoginID = '$LoginID' AND password ='$password'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select a field possibly the `id` for the user instead of doing a count.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM User WHERE LoginID = '$LoginID' AND password ='$password'"))

if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // valid
} else {
    // invalid
}
```